# Bypass openpyxl data validation extension in python?

Tags: python, excel, validation, openpyxl

I currently have a pandas dataframe that I am importing into an already formatted excel worksheet. On one of the other worksheets in the workbook, I am using an Excel data validation dropdown list.

Here is the current code I have:

```
file= "Test.xlsm"

book = load_workbook(file, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

writer.book = book
writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='UnitDB', startrow = 3, starcol =1, index=False, header = False)
writer.save()
```

The program successfully executes, except for a warning I get.

```
UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed.
```

In my Excel workbook where I just wrote my dataframe into, I notice all my instances in other worksheets of data validation lists have been removed.

I understand that this may be a limitation of openpyxl in not being able to understand data validation, but is there a way I can have openpyxl ignore this, so that my current data validation is able to remain as is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this error by creating a variable in the formula name manager, which contains my range of cells that I was using in the data validation tool originally. Then, when going to data validation, I simply typed in =myvariablename instead of the range of cells.